# How to pass only element s1 and s2 instead of entire array int e1.setEmployeeSkill?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

[image]

This is the main method from where I am trying to pass values to the skill class which accepts array. I do not want to give employee e1 all the skills but just s4, how can I do that so my code becomes logical and correct

Comment: Please do not use images for code - update the question with the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You have different way to achieve this.
Taking into consideration the piece of code you showed above, the easiest way to do that which doesn't imply to add any additional method to the `Employee` class, is to create a new array of `Skill` while invoking `setEmployeesSkills` on `e1`, so your code will appear more or less like this:

```
e1.setEmployeesSkills(new Skill[]{s4});
```

Hope that is what you are looking for, otherwise please share more info and I will try to help you further.